# Performance Issue: convert csv to excel using Powershell

Tags: java, excel, powershell

I am using below power shell code to convert csv to excel. But the performance seems bad, for a 200mb csv file, I've been waiting for 20 mins. Anyone have idea how to improve the performance. Or do I have to do pragmatically, (using java using apache poi library)?

```
   function convertToExcel { 
   param($fileName, $outputDir) # the two parameters. 
   #generate OutputFileName
   $outputFilename = -join($fileName.BaseName, ".xlsx"); 

   #prepare excel sheet
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    #$excel.visible = $true
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.add()
    $sheets = $workbook.sheets
    $sheetCount = $Sheets.count
    $mySheet = 1
    $mySheetName = "Sheet" + $mySheet
    $s1 = $sheets | where{$_.name -eq $mySheetName}
    $s1.Activate()

    #Delete all other Sheets
    If ($sheetCount -gt 1) {
        $Sheets | ForEach {
            $tmpSheetName = $_.Name
            $tmpSheet = $_
            If ($tmpSheetName -ne "Sheet1") {
                $tmpSheet.Delete()
            }
        }
    }

   #copy paste data from csv
   #$s1.Name = $fileName.BaseName
   $s1.Name = "sheet1"
   $s1.Activate()
   $s1Data = Import-Csv $file.FullName -Delimiter '^'
   $s1Data | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Clip
   $s1.cells.item(1,1).Select()
   $s1.Paste()

   $workbook.SaveAs("$outputDir\$outputFilename")
   $excel.Quit()
   } 

   #Read Input from Arguments
   if ($args.length -ne 3){
   }else{
   $fileName = $Args[0]   #read fileName
   $inputFolder = $Args[1] #read inputFolder
   $outputFolder = $Args[2] #read outputFolder

   $files = dir -Path $inputFolder $fileName

   ForEach ($file in $files) {
   convertToExcel $file $outputFolder
  }
 }
```

Comment: Do you need to convert such CSV files frequently? Would the investment of time to rewrite the script in Java be worth it, or can you just go away and get lunch while it is running?

Comment: Yes, I would need it to run frequently. it is for weekly report. the report can be up to a few hundreds MB.

Comment: Have you considered opening the CSV file in excel directly?

Comment: Does it matter if it takes 20min+ once a week? I don't consider that frequent (I was meaning many times each day when I asked if it was run frequently)

Comment: After your `$excel.Quit()`, don't forget to `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)` and `Remove-Variable excel` or else Excel will not exit and you will leak references.

Comment: Hi Kory, thank you. let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just opening a CSV file in Excel? This is probably the fastest method.

```
$app = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$app.Visible = $true
$app.DisplayAlerts = $False
$app.Workbooks.Open("yourcsvfile.csv")
```

The other way would be reading the file by rows and adding entire rows, but it will be slower.

However, converting to PS object and writing cell by cell will always be slowest.

**Edit**: Here is a full function...

```
function ConvertToExcel { 
    param($fileName)    
    $outputFilename = -join($fileName.split('.')[0], ".xls")
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    #$excel.Visible = $true
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
    $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($fileName)
    $wb.SaveAs("$outputFilename", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlExcel8)
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
    $excel.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
    Remove-Variable excel
}

ConvertToExcel "D:\tst\serverlist.csv"
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware that excel can open csv directly.. The thing is I need to convert it into excel automatically. without I click open excel and save as.

Comment: Don't follow, the code above will open csv and you already have code to save it as xls. No buttons involved.

Comment: I have added full function to the answer.